# how to change Devise custom views path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hello is there is a way to change the default views path of devise, cause if a run the `rails g devise:views admin` will generate a admin folder inside views folder. If i change this folder location like move from views/admins to `views/backend/admins` devise wont find and use the default views instead.

The same problem is in `rails g devise:controllers admin` devise wont find the custom controllers if the folder isn't on `app/controllers`

here is my `Routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :admins, skip: :registration, path: '/backend'

namespace :backend do
    #devise_for :admin, module: 'admin', skip: :registration #i've already try somethings like this but wont work
    resource :static_pages, path: '', only: [] do
        root to:'static_pages#dashboard'
    end
end
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know that **ALL** your admin controllers with be accessing this 'backend' path then you can do the following:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_theme

  def set_theme
    prepend_view_path "app/views/backend"
  end
end
```

Then ensure that your admin controllers inherit from AdminController and you may need to play around with the path a bit to suit your setup.

*This approach is pinched from Tuts+, check it out [there](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/build-a-cms-with-rails/lessons/templates-and-themes-part-1) if you can.

Comment: this wont work, still using the devise default views =/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i do:

i run the `rails g devise:controllers admin` and get all controllers of admin in `app/controllers/admins` then i move it to `app/controllers/backend/admins` and change the header of each controller to be like this:
`class Backend::Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController`

but i already have in `backend_controller.rb` a file called `app/controllers/` wihch have simply:

```
class BackendController < ApplicationController
end
```

and my `routes.rb` become like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :admins, module: 'backend/admins', path: '/backend', skip: :registration
...
```

so i can organize and create a view in my `app/views/backend/admins/` like `app/views/backend/admins/sessions/new.html.erb`

basically i use the `rails g devise:views admins` and move the folder inside the backend folder.